# How with ffmpeg one char with different color?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to ffmpeg one char with different color?

I have draw text with ffmpeg, but I can't find how I can change only one character's color. All text I can change, but I need one char with a different color.

I have this part of code:

```
   ffmpeg -f lavfi \
    -i color=c=white:s=1280x720 \
    -vf "drawtext=text='aaaaaaaaBaaaaa':\
    fontcolor=black:\
    fontsize=24:\"
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 -y out.mp4 ");
```

But I can't figure out how need change letter `B` to red

Comment: Use [ASS](https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/ssa.html)

Comment: can't you use 2 drawtext.

Comment: Then i can't detect position of "B"